# How to make Ubuntu working with tablet?

Tags: unity, firefox, touchscreen

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my tablet pc as main operating system but it was really hard to make it working with touch screen.

The system reacts on touch and mouse click differently and it produces bugs which make it hard to use at all.

I tried all major desktops - Unity, Gnome, LXDE, KDE etc, and only Unity works relatively good with touch screen. But Unity also has touch screen bugs - for example, it is impossible to use Firefox or Chrome. When I tap on menu button in Firefox (it is rightmost button, contains zoom, print, history, full screen command etc) it does nothing. When I tap on any combobox in Firefox, it blinks for a moment and disappears - so it is impossible to use comboboxes. Tabs in Chrome also dont work - if I tap on tab Chrome does not switch to the tab. Note that if I use mouse everything works.
If I switch to other desktop, for example, KDE, Chrome and Firefox start working with taps, but KDE has more serious bug - it stops reacting on taps after some time passed, I cannot say the reason. Also on-screen keyboard works very bad in KDE - it does not show up automatically, sometimes it even does not show up on login screen. It is not a problem if you have keyboard, but if you have only touch screen....

So I reverted back to Windows on the tabled and continue to use Ubuntu on my desktop as there are no such problems.

I would be very glad if someone could help me with taps on Unity.

Thanks,
Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to calibrate your touch screen. Not all touch screens work with Ubuntu out of the box. Therefore, if you can look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) for more on calibration. Scroll down to "Calibration" and read about xinput-calibrator. This should allow you to calibrate your screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think it is not the case. Even if I log out and then switch to LXDE (for example), comboboxes and other UI elements start to work.

Comment: @user3267791 You are saying that the bugs are specific to Unity? And by "only Unity works relatively good with touch screen." are you saying you don't like the UI of the programs, or that the touch input is broken?

Comment: yes touch input is broken and I have problems with all major desktops but Unity looks better compared to others - at least it is possible to work if you don't want to use Firefox/Chrome

Comment: You might look for a browser that is made for touch. You may want to consider Opera Mobile according to [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/opera-mobile-11-the-best-touch-screen-browser-for-ubuntu). If your having problems with touch, it is probably that your screen is not sensitive enough, so you should use a program that is made for touch screens. If you are really into firefox, you #might# be able to compile the windows 8 app (though this is very unlikely to work). Ubuntu is not a tablet OS, so you shouldn't expect touch to work amazingly.